# SQL convert date dmmyyyy and ddmmyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql-server, date, converters

I have the following problem.
I have some dates with the following format '15122019' and I need it in this format 2019-12-15, which I already solved it in the following way.

```
select convert (date, Stuff(Stuff('15122018',5,0,'.'),3,0,'.'),104)
```

The real problem is when the dates come like this '3122019' the conversion can not be done because the length is shorter. Is ther e another way to do it? I've been trying to solve it for several hours. And another question, can this query be parameterized?

Comment: but what date would `'2122018'` be?, `2018-02-21` or `2018-12-02`?

Comment: Can you have shortened months as well. So you might get something like 312019?

Comment: the month is not shortened, the date would be 2019-12-03

Comment: My example was January 3rd. But you would get 3012019?

Comment: I have this 3122019 and i need this 2019-12-03

Comment: Right you mentioned that. I am trying to make sure a solution to that actually solves the problem. What would you have for January 3, 2019? I also fear that you are trying to manage this still as character data. It should instead be converted to a date, then do the formatting outside of the database.

Comment: oh sorry , as you mentioned before '3012019'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 DECLARE @date VARCHAR(20)
 SET @date ='3122019'

 IF(LEN(@date) = 8)
 BEGIN  
    SET @date = Stuff(Stuff(@date,5,0,'.'),3,0,'.');
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @date , 103);
 END
 ELSE IF(LEN(@date) = 7) 
 BEGIN

    SET @date = Stuff(Stuff(@date,4,0,'.'),2,0,'.');
    IF(ISDATE(@date)=1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @date , 103);          
    END    
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @date = Stuff(Stuff(@date,4,0,'.'),3,0,'.');    
            SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @date , 103);
    END
 END
 ELSE IF(LEN(@date) = 6)
 BEGIN
     SET @date = Stuff(Stuff(@date,3,0,'.'),2,0,'.');
     SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @date , 103);
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Such conversation can be achieved by:

- Casting integer value to DATE using intermediate FORMAT transformation to a recognizable for conversation string pattern.

  - style 105 applied to match the input as `dd-mm-yyyy`
  - style 05 to match `dd-mm-yy`

SQL:

```
-- input format: dmmyyyy
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, FORMAT(3012019, '##-##-####'), 105)
-- result: 2019-01-03

-- input format: dmmyy
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, FORMAT(30119, '##-##-##'), 05)
-- result: 2019-01-03
```

This will work fine with a single (and double) digit day number, however, it indeed requires a double-digit month

Answer (score 0):

You can add `0` to the left and take 8 chars with `right`. like `RIGHT('0'+'15122018',8)`. it work with 15122018 and 3122018

```
select convert (date, Stuff(Stuff( RIGHT('0'+'15122018',8) ,5,0,'.'),3,0,'.'),104)
```